# Automatic translation for HTML files

Tags: html, localization, language-translation

I want translate a web page for multiple languages. I can create a .html file for each language, but I would like only one .html file and use an automatic way for translations.

Is it be possible?

Comment: Are you asking whether a *static* HTML page can automatically be translated into many languages depending on the localization of the viewer? Or are you asking how this can be accomplished via server side scripting?

Comment: Google translate the whole thing after it's loaded? :)

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible for a static website. I suggest you stick to having separate files for each locale.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way for you to achieve that (since you are obviously the beginner) would be to actually use PHP and generate appropriate language web page on the fly.

Alternatively (but I must warn you that this approach may result in very unresponsive web page) you can use JavaScript to translate your web page - in fact [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) plus [Globalize](https://github.com/jquery/globalize). However, this force you to use common anti-pattern, that is you would need to force users to choose their language as oppose to automatically infer it from web browser's settings.

Either way, you have a lot of things to learn...